# Modifying array items in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2

I found some really strange behavior in Swift. Here's the code:

```
var array2d: [[Int]] = [[1]]
print(array2d) // prints [[1]]

var first = array2d[0]
first.append(2)

print(array2d) // still prints [[1]]!!!
```

I would totally expect the last line to print `[[1, 2]]`. I can't explain the current behavior. I'd expect `array2d[0]` to return a reference to the first item, or possibly a copy of that reference. In either case, modifying that object should modify `array2d`. But that's not what's happening.

If, however, I update the array like this:

```
array2d[0].append(2)
```

it then prints `[[1, 2]]`, as expected.

Can someone please explain this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How arrays are referenced/passed around/copied in swift is a point of a lot of contention, take a look at [this link](http://natecook.com/blog/2014/06/swift-array-copying-ambiguity/).

In essence what is happening is that `var first = array2d[0]` is taking a copy of the array at that index as opposed to creating a reference as you were expecting. Hence accessing the array with the subscript notation allows to you to correctly alter the array but creating a new variable doesn't.

Comment: So in other words, it makes a deep copy of everything?